Redirect after adding Pass
After I add a pass using pkpass, how do I redirect back to my home page?
I have multiple buttons on a webpage that use PKPass->create() to return the zipped pkpass file.  The pass is added just fine but afterwards, I have no idea how to return to the original web page.
